# How to query a parse table into a listview on android?

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform

I've been trying for a while now but all my methods failed.  Recently I saw an example and I tried it but it also failed.

This is my code if anybody could see where I went wrong I'm trying to get a table from parse that is called `Projects` that contains the following attributes:
`ID`, `Name`, `Category`, `Description` and `Students` and put it in a `ListView` to be displayed

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;


public class UserPage extends ListActivity {
private List<Projects> projects;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_page);

    projects = new ArrayList<Projects>();

    ArrayAdapter<Projects> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Projects>(this,
            R.layout.activity_user_page, projects);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    refreshPostList();
}

private void refreshPostList(){
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Projects");

    final ProgressDialog mProgress;
    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(UserPage.this);
    mProgress.setTitle("Generating Projects");
    mProgress.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgress.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgress.show();

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>(){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void done(List<ParseObject> projectList,ParseException e){
            if(e==null){
                projects.clear();
                for(ParseObject post :projectList){
                    Projects project = new Projects(post.getObjectId(),post.getString("ProjectName"), post.getString("Category"), post.getString("Description"), post.getString("Students"));
                    projects.add(project);
                }
                ((ArrayAdapter<Projects>) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Error:"+ e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting data back from the query?

Comment: I think I'm getting the data because the error message is not showing